# Access 2016 Return The First Record Only Where Field Contains Different Text

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to write a query to return the first record of each group in a table.

The table contains multiple duplicate playerIds and some of the bowlingStyle fields contain different text (most are identical).

I just want to return a list of playerIds with the first bowlingStyle.

I thought this would work but it still returns multiple playerIds where the bowlingStyle fields contain different text.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

```
SELECT First(Lineups.playerId), First(Lineups.bowlingStyle)
FROM Lineups
GROUP BY Lineups.playerId, Lineups.bowlingStyle;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value returned by the function [`FIRST()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/first-last-functions-acd76019-c37f-432d-9807-4fc63cac1db5) is arbitrary if the dataset is not ordered.
So select from a query that sorts the table by some column like `id` (AutoNumber) or a date (if it exists) and then `group by playerId` only:

```
SELECT playerId, First(bowlingStyle) AS First_bowlingStyle
FROM (SELECT * FROM Lineups ORDER BY id)
GROUP BY playerId
```